# SQL Server query don't retrieves expected result

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two tables: `certificate` and `store`. I have to write a query to return certificates that have a `store_id` in store_id or fk_store_id columns in `store` table. This query has to be filtered by person_id and store_id.

I've already tried some queries, but it don't bind the correct certificate with the right store.

This is my certificate table:

```
STORE_ID | CERTIFICATE_ID | PERSON_ID
---------|----------------|----------
1464     | 87083          | 100258
336      | 87123          | 100258
```

This is my store table:

```
STORE_ID | FK_STORE_ID | STORE_DESC
---------|-------------|---------------
336      | 1464        | A First Store
1117     | 1464        | Store two
1464     | 340         | The Third
```

I've built this query:

```
SELECT 
    S.STORE_ID
    ,S.FK_STORE_ID, C.STORE_ID AS CERTIFICATE_STORE_ID
    ,C.PERSON_ID
    ,CERTIFICATE_ID 
FROM CERTIFICATE C 
     INNER JOIN STORE S ON C.STORE_ID = S.STORE_ID OR C.STORE_ID = S.FK_STORE_ID
WHERE 
    C.PERSON_ID = 100258    
    AND C.STORE_ID = 1464
```

This query retrieves:

```
STORE_ID | FK_STORE_ID | STORE_ID | PERSON_ID | CERTIFICATE_ID
---------|-------------|----------|-----------|----------------
336      | 1464        | 1464     |  100258   | 87083
1117     | 1464        | 1464     |  100258   | 87083
1464     | 340         | 1464     |  100258   | 87083
```

I expected to get this:

```
STORE_ID | FK_STORE_ID | CERTIFICATE_STORE_ID | PERSON_ID | CERTIFICATE_ID
---------|-------------|----------------------|-----------|----------------
336      | 1464        | 336                  |  100258   | 87123
1464     | 340         | 1464                 |  100258   | 87083
```

Is there any way to get this, without change the table structure?

Need your help, thanks!

Comment: Why do you not expect to get Store_ID 1117?

Comment: Based on your data it does not make ANY sense to not expect `STORE_ID` 1117.

Comment: Also, your filter has `C.STORE_ID = 1464` which is only associated with `CERTIFICATE_ID 87083`

Comment: I'm wondering if you should just join on store id and then filter with the OR statement.

Comment: The most absurd thing is that you are using `SELECT C.STORE_ID AS CERTIFICATE_STORE_ID` and `WHERE C.STORE_ID = 1464` and expect it to possibly be `336`.

Comment: I think you are looking for what @JohnPasquet said.  Join on only `STORE_ID` and then change your filter to `WHERE C.PERSON_ID = 100258 AND (C.STORE_ID = 1464 OR S.FK_STORE_ID = 1464)`

Comment: @JohnPasquet and mo2 answers solved my problem. Thanks guys!

Comment: I've put that in answer form now.  That way this question won't be "hanging" without one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented above, it seemed you needed the OR in the filter rather than on the join.

So, here is my comment in answer form...

```
SELECT 
    S.STORE_ID
    ,S.FK_STORE_ID, C.STORE_ID AS CERTIFICATE_STORE_ID
    ,C.PERSON_ID
    ,CERTIFICATE_ID 
FROM CERTIFICATE C 
     INNER JOIN STORE S ON C.STORE_ID = S.STORE_ID
WHERE 
    C.PERSON_ID = 100258    
    AND (C.STORE_ID = 1464 OR C.FS_STORE_ID = 1464)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be some thing like this,

```
SELECT 
    S.STORE_ID, S.FK_STORE_ID, C.STORE_ID AS CERTIFICATE_STORE_ID, 
    C.PERSON_ID, CERTIFICATE_ID 
FROM dbo.Certificates c
     INNER JOIN dbo.Store s ON C.STORE_ID = S.STORE_ID 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
     S.STORE_ID, S.FK_STORE_ID, C.STORE_ID AS CERTIFICATE_STORE_ID, 
     C.PERSON_ID, CERTIFICATE_ID 
FROM dbo.Certificates c
     INNER JOIN dbo.Store s ON C.STORE_ID = S.FK_STORE_ID
WHERE  C.PERSON_ID = 100258
     AND S.STORE_ID = 1464
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this given code will serve your goal:

```
SELECT a.store_id,
       a.fk_store_id,
       b.store_id,
       b.certificate_id,
       b.person_id
  FROM (SELECT store_id, fk_store_id
          FROM store
         WHERE store_id IN
                  (SELECT store_id
                     FROM certificate
                    WHERE    store_id IN (SELECT store_id FROM store)
                          OR     store_id IN (SELECT fk_store_id FROM store)
                             AND person_id = '100258'
                             AND store_id = '1464')) a,
       (SELECT store_id, CERTIFICATE_ID, PERSON_ID
          FROM certificate
         WHERE    store_id IN (SELECT store_id FROM store)
               OR     store_id IN (SELECT fk_store_id FROM store)
                  AND person_id = '100258'
                  AND store_id = '1464') b
 WHERE a.store_id = b.store_id;
```